# oracle timestamp to jodatime not working

Tags: jodatime

I am having a timestamp stored in DB in oracle as which is AEST time zone

```
             25-03-17 01:04:59.916000000 AM
```

I want to convert it into Jodatime this AEST time zone

```
             2017-03-25T01:04:59.916+11:00

    String text = "2017-03-25 01:04:59.916000000 AM";
    Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(text);
    System.out.println("Timestamp: " + timestamp);

    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(timestamp,AEST);
   // DateTime d=dateTime.toDateTime();
    System.out.println("DateTime: " + dateTime);
```

Tried this but this does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that **AEST** is the **Australia/Sidney** timezone, you can do this:

```
DateTimeZone dtz = DateTimeZone.forID("Australia/Sydney");
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(timestamp).withZoneRetainFields(dtz);
System.out.println("DateTime: " + dateTime);
```

The output will be:

```
DateTime: 2017-03-25T01:04:59.916+11:00
```

Unfortunatelly, passing `"AEST"` to `forID` method doesn't work, you must pass the equivalent id (which is `"Australia/Sidney"`).